# Error when extracting data from Gmail email body with Python

Tags: python

I need to access my gmail account and search for an email that contains a specific text, I was able to log in, but I always receive the error below:

> "Error when fetching email: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
> '\xf3' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)"

I've tried countless treatments with regex without success.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import imaplib
import email
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

def connect_to_gmail(email_address, password):
    try:
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
        status, response = mail.login(email_address, password)

        if status == 'OK':
            mail.select('inbox')
            status, email_ids = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

            if status == 'OK':
                email_count = len(email_ids[0].split())
                print(f'Login no Gmail bem-sucedido. Total de {email_count} emails na caixa de entrada.')  # Mensagem de log com a contagem
                return mail
            else:
                raise Exception(f'Erro ao contar emails na caixa de entrada. Resposta do servidor: {response}')
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Erro ao conectar ao Gmail. Resposta do servidor: {response}')
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'Erro ao conectar ao Gmail: {str(e)}')

def search_email(mail, search_subject):
    try:
        search_criteria = f'HEADER Subject "{search_subject}"'
        email_data = email.message_from_bytes(mail.fetch(mail.search(None, search_criteria), '(RFC822)')[0][1]).decode('latin-1')

        msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_data)
        print(msg.get_payload(decode=True))

        return email_data
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'Erro ao buscar email: {str(e)}')

def extract_code(email_data):
    try:
        msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_data)
        charset = msg.get_content_charset() or 'utf-8'

        body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode(charset, 'latin-1')

        code_match = re.search(r'Insira o código a seguir para a verificação:\s*(\d+)', body)

        if code_match:
            return code_match.group(1)
        else:
            raise Exception('Código numérico não encontrado no email.')
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'Erro ao extrair código numérico: {str(e)}')



@app.route('/token', methods=['GET'])
def get_token():
    email_address = 'email@gmail.com'
    password = 'password'
    search_subject = 'Fwd: Código de verificação único'

    try:
        mail = connect_to_gmail(email_address, password)
        email_data = search_email(mail, search_subject)
        token = extract_code((email_data))
        print(token)
        return jsonify({'message': 'Token obtido com sucesso', 'token': token})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'd say trying to decode it with `latin-1` is your problem.  Confirm the email has been encoded with `latin-1` or switch to the appropriate encoding.